# How do I make the checkbox work on newly created task?

Tags: javascript, loops, dom, checkbox

I am writing a todo app using vanilla JavaScript to learn the language without using a library. 
In the app, you can add a task, complete task or un-complete task, edit and delete task. I have sample tasks that show the functionality in HTML. 
I have a function that adds a task to incomplete tasks section—each task item is wrapped in an li tag and has a checkbox, edit and delete buttons. The addTask function works perfectly. 
The problem I am having is in the selectbox part. The app is designed in a way that when checkbox of a task is selected, it indicates a task is completed and thus the item is shown in the completed tasks section. The function works for the items available on the page but not the ones added using the add functionality. How do I make the new task work? Thanks. Here is my HTML Code:

```
<h3>Todo</h3>
<ul id="incomplete-tasks">
  <li><input type="checkbox"><label>Pay Bills</label><button>Edit</button><button>Delete</button></li>
</ul>

<h3>Completed</h3>
<ul id="completed-tasks">
  <li><input type="checkbox" checked></input><label>See Doctor</label><button>Edit</button><button>Delete</button></li>
```

And here is my JS code:

```
var incompleteTasksHolder = document.getElementById("incomplete-tasks");
var completedTasksHolder = document.getElementById("competed-tasks");
var incompleteTextboxes = incompleteTasksHolder.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");


for (var i = 0; i < incompleteTextboxes.length; i++) {
  incompleteTextboxes[i].onfocus = function() {
    var item = this.parentNode;
    this.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    completedTasksHolder.appendChild(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show all the relevant code. That would include HTML.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks Scott. I have added the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using some event listeners to mark the task as completed when the checkbox changes value.

I think that you just forgot the bind this listener to the new item that you created via Javascript.

When creating your new element bind your listener to it:

`taskCB.addEventListener('change', toggleCompleted);`

Where `taskCB` is the checkbox element and `toggleCompleted` is the name of the function that is fired when a task checkbox is checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens because the `incompleteTextboxes` variable only gets assigned a collection of DOM nodes once. Each time you add a new task, that ends up inside `incompleteTasksHolder` you should also re-assign an updated collection by re-running the assignment: `incompleteTextboxes = incompleteTasksHolder.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");`.

That could look something like this:

```
var incompleteTasksHolder = document.getElementById("incomplete-tasks"),
    completedTasksHolder  = document.getElementById("competed-tasks");

// Initialize variable, but create a function for the assignment:
var incompleteTextboxes;

// This function searches the DOM for all checkboxes inside incompleteTasksHolder, and assigns the collection of found elements to incompleteTextboxes:
function refreshIncompleteTasksCollection() {
    incompleteTextboxes = incompleteTasksHolder.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
}

// You can now re-assign all currently existing checkboxes by calling this function:
refreshIncompleteTasksCollection();
```

Now, each time there are new elements inside `incompletetextboxes`, you can run that function to add those to your collection. Note, you'll probably want to re-run your for-loop as well, for binding the focus event handler to your new elements.

A whole different (and in my opinion cleaner) approach would be to use event delegation for your onfocus handlers. Since `incompletetextboxes` only contains checkboxes inside `#incomplete-tasks` (by the way you set up your variables), you could use that element to delegate the event handling to. This can be done with `addEventListener`. You can read more about that here: https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate.

The main reason I bring this up is because this would solve the problem of missing event handlers for your new elements. What event delegation basically means is, instead of saying:

listen at each `incompleteTextbox` for a focus event (which means that, when you add new elements you have to say that again for each new element)

you now say:

listen at `incompleteTasksHolder` for a focus event, and then determine whether that event was fired by a `incompleteTextbox`. That is possible because your checkboxes live INSIDE `#incomplete-tasks`. That could look something like this:

```
incompleteTasksHolder.addEventListener("focus", function(eventObject) {

  if (eventObject.target && eventObject.target.matches("input[type=checkbox]")) {
      // eventObject.target is the checkbox you want to work with

      var checkbox = eventObject.target;
      // YOUR CODE:
      var item = checkbox.parentNode;
      checkbox.setAttribute("checked", "checked");
      completedTasksHolder.appendChild(item);  
  }
});
```

That means only one listener, that will always work, even for `incompleteTextboxes` that are inserted after that listener was set.